# wikitude image recognition in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, wikitude

i always error

this my activity

public class ARActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

```
ArchitectView arview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_cam);

    this.arview = (ArchitectView) findViewById(R.id.architectView);
    final ArchitectConfig config = new ArchitectConfig(
            WikitudeSDKConstants.WIKITUDE_SDK_KEY);
    this.arview.onCreate(config);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.arview.onPostCreate();
    try {
        this.arview.load("assets/wikitude/imageRecognition/index.html");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and this my xml

and i get error

please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the Wiktiude SDK Sample App, which is part of the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/download).
It comes with a "AbstractArchitectCamFragmentV4.java" and a "AbstractArchitectCamActivity.java", which define the required lifecycle methods properly.

I guess implementing the remaining onResume, onPause, onDestroy should solve the issue.

Kind regards,
Andreas